# How to register new Images in the Eucalyptus webinterface?

Tags: eucalyptus

Installed the Faststart image on a single machine. Everything works. I also followed [the blog](http://blogs.mindspew-age.com/tag/ubuntu-cloud-image/)
 to install the Ubuntu image. Its also running from the command line. And I can ssh onto it. So all fine.

*Now the question*: how can I add the Image (or the 3 parts(kernel,ramdisk,image)) to the webinterface(port 8888) such that I can start an instance from there? Like it is done for the centos image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot currently register an image using the web interface, but you can use euca2ools from the command line to bundle, upload and register images which will then be available for use via the web interface:

https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#image-guide/img_add_existing.html

You can find an overview of image management tasks here:

https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#image-guide/img_task_intro.html